# Returning a vector(return type)

Tags: c++, object, vector, reference, return

I'm just a step away from finally grasping the full use and concept of pointers and references(or so i hope), so i need your help to make matters clear.

I have a `private` member vector of `ClassA` that contains an object, so `vector<myObj> vec`.

What kind of getter should I use in `ClassA` to return the `vec` so I can print contents of `myObj` without redundantly allocating memory?
Do i need to `return` vec by `reference`, regular `return vec`, or maybe even a pointer to `vec`

Comment: A `const &` reference would be the most appropriate IMHO.

Comment: thanks, others seem to agree

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return by *constant reference*:

```
const vector<myObj>& ClassA::getVec() const{
    return vec;
}
```

This means that (i) no value copy is taken and (ii) the caller cannot modify the reference which helps gain program stability.

Notice how I've made the member function `const` as well. This means that you can call this function from a constant instance of `ClassA`.

Comment: care to elaborate a little more, or provide a link

Comment: Thanks. Last question, if that wasn't a `getter` but rather a function that alters `vec` and then `return`s it, would that change the type?

Comment: @user2202368 If you want to preserve the original vector in the class, you would need to return by value, as the reference of the copy of the vector would be invalidated when the instruction pointer goes out of scope of the vector copy.

Comment: @Erbureth so no `const` and `&` are needed?

Comment: @user2202368 If you are returning a local copy, `&` is not possible and `const` inhibits [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) when you return by value

Answer (score 2):

You can return const reference to the vector:

```
const vector<myObj>& get() const
{
  return vec;
}
```